# Update SQL value with JSON in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

I spent the entire day yesterday trying to debug this, and I couldn't make any progress. The situation: I am using Phonegap to create an app for the iOS platform. I am using a database with tables to store various pieces of data (it's a golf score card app). Right now I am trying to store an object array in my courses table but it is returning the error code "Error: could not prepare statment (1 near "blah": syntax error) code:5 "

Here is the code that is causing issues.

```
//for example
var string = JSON.stringify(['dag', 'woah']);
db.transaction(function (tx){
            tx.executeSql('UPDATE courses SET holes_info = "' + string + '" WHERE course_id = "' + course_id + '"', [], nullHandler, errorHandler);
        });
```

In my courses table, the holes_info column is set to datatype TEXT. So this code DOES work if I make string = JSON.stringify([1,2,3]). If I use integers in the array it works go figure, but if I use text it doesn't. I tried mixing it up with single and double quotes, but that didn't help either. My goal is to store an array of objects that looks like this...

```
var hole_object = {
    "par": 0,
    "yards": 0,
    "score":0,
    "drives":0,
    "irons": 0,
    "wedges": 0,
    "putts": 0,
    "strokes": 0
};
```

Every time it says there is an "1 near "par": syntax error". Another person on stackoverflow asked a similar question and said that using escape for example...

```
var string = escape(JSON.stringify(['dag', 'woah']));
```

But that didn't help either. So I have tried everything I could think of to get this to work but nothing will behave. If I have to I will just create a table for each course which will hold the hole_object array data, but I want to see if there is a way to make the above work first.

Thanks again for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use parameters:

```
tx.executeSql("UPDATE courses SET holes_info = ? WHERE course_id = ?",
              [string, course_id], nullHandler, errorHandler);
```

Comment: CL, I will give that a try soon as I can here. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I didn't know you could use parameters like that either, so thanks for teaching me two new things aha.